# -like with multiple patterns

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is there an easy way (not using loops) to apply -like with more than one pattern to one string?

so

```
"c:\myfile.txt" -like "*.dat","*.txt"
```

should return $true

```
"c:\myfile.dat" -like "*.dat","*.txt"
```

should return $true

> "c:\myfile.doc" -like "*.dat","*.txt"

should return $false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. You could use regular expression:

```
"c:\myfile.txt" -match '^.+\.(dat|txt)$'
```

UPDATE

Make a regex pattern from input that contains a wildcard patterns:

```
    PS> $or = '"*.dat","*.txt","*.foo"' -replace '"|\*\.'  -replace ',','|'
    PS> $pattern = '^.+({0})$' -f $or
    PS> $pattern 
    ^.+(dat|txt|foo)$

   $string -match $pattern
```

Comment: unfortunatelly, this is how i get these strings from the script input parameters - *.dat","*.txt. it is string array. so i guess foreach is my only option here?

Comment: You can process the input and make a regex pattern out of it. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `-match` instead of `-like` here:

```
"c:\myfile.txt" -match "\.(dat|txt)$" ==> True
"c:\myfile.dat" -match "\.(dat|txt)$" ==> True
"c:\myfile.doc" -match "\.(dat|txt)$" ==> False
```